# PHP: Query attribute does not appear

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

**Situation :** I ran a query like this:

```
$result_final = $this->db->query($strSQL);
```

I echo the query, which is as follows:

```
SELECT marksobtained, studentid, pc_z_13_9 .schoolid, pc_z_13_9 .sessionid, pc_z_13_9 .sectionid FROM pc_z_13_9 WHERE pc_z_13_9 .masterclassid = 13 AND pc_z_13_9 .subjectmasterid = 9 AND pc_z_13_9 .schoolid = 223 AND pc_z_13_9 .sessionid = 595 AND pc_z_13_9 .sectionid = 897 AND pc_z_13_9 .examid = 137 ORDER BY studentid ;
```

**Problem :** I did the following.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row1)
    {
        print_r($row1);
```

Surprisingly, print_r does NOT list 'studentid'! In the query its the 2nd param. But it lists all other attributes of the query.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Also, running the same query on the database shows the StudentID column, and its values.

Comment: why is your query inconsistent? (you prepend the table name for some columns and not for the others)

Comment: Hi Tomas Cot. I get the same result now that I've appended the table name on all columns:
SELECT pc_z_13_9.marksobtained,pc_z_13_9.studentid, pc_z_13_9 .schoolid, pc_z_13_9 .sessionid, pc_z_13_9 .sectionid FROM pc_z_13_9 WHERE pc_z_13_9 .masterclassid = 13 AND pc_z_13_9 .subjectmasterid = 9 AND pc_z_13_9 .schoolid = 223 AND pc_z_13_9 .sessionid = 595 AND pc_z_13_9 .sectionid = 897 AND pc_z_13_9 .examid = 137 ORDER BY pc_z_13_9.studentid ;

Comment: As I said, running the same query directly on the database returns all the columns, including 'studentid'.

Comment: OK here's my next question: How do I delete a silly question ?

Comment: just update it with the answer, it could be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sorry my question was wrong.

Instead of

```
foreach ($**query**->result() as $row1)
```

it should be

```
foreach ($result_final->result() as $row1)
```

A very stupid error on my part. It happened due to oversight.